# Why does matrix exponential not work beyond certain size?

Tags: python, scipy, exponentiation

I'm having trouble with the matrix exponential calculation using scipy.linalg.expm.

```
The code is like this:
import numpy as np    
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.linalg as linA 
from scipy.sparse.linalg import expm 

linA.expm(sp.kron(np.arange(N), np.identity(2)))
```

where, N can be any integer, number is an NxN diagonal matrix with diagonal elements diag{0,1,2, ... N-1}, and sp.kron is a kronecker product in scipy.sparse. This works fine only for N<6. When I try to run the code with N=6

```
linA.expm(sp.kron(np.arange(6), np.identity(2)))
```

This should be a fairly simple code, but I don't know why it is giving the following error:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-168-b0f10db2dd69> in <module>
----> 1 linA.expm(sp.kron(number(6), identity(2)) )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\matfuncs.py in expm(A)
    253     # Input checking and conversion is provided by sparse.linalg.expm().
    254     import scipy.sparse.linalg
--> 255     return scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(A)
    256 
    257 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py in expm(A)
    590             [  0.        ,   0.        ,  20.08553692]])
    591     """
--> 592     return _expm(A, use_exact_onenorm='auto')
    593 
    594 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py in _expm(A, use_exact_onenorm)
    675     if structure == UPPER_TRIANGULAR:
    676         # Invoke Code Fragment 2.1.
--> 677         X = _fragment_2_1(X, h.A, s)
    678     else:
    679         # X = r_13(A)^(2^s) by repeated squaring.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py in _fragment_2_1(X, T, s)
    811             lam_1 = scale * diag_T[k]
    812             lam_2 = scale * diag_T[k+1]
--> 813             t_12 = scale * T[k, k+1]
    814             value = _eq_10_42(lam_1, lam_2, t_12)
    815             X[k, k+1] = value

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\bsr.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    313 
    314     def __getitem__(self,key):
--> 315         raise NotImplementedError
    316 
    317     def __setitem__(self,key,val):

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: What's `sp.kron`?  `scipy.sparse?  If so include a `sparse matrix` tag.  The error indicates we need to study the sparse.linalg code.

Comment: You don't specify `number`, so we can't replicate or explore your problem.  You say `N=6` is the limit, but don't tell us anything about the size of the matrix (and type?) that you pass to `expm`.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We don't know how you defined or imported the names `linA`, `sp`, and `number`.  It looks like `linA` might be `scipy.sparse.linalg`, but it would be better if we didn't have to guess.

Comment: For other `N` have you been getting efficiency warnings?  Did you try to act on those?  @WarrenWeckesser, I did some code tracing.  `kron` is producing a `bsr` format matrix, but only for 'upper triangular' ones is it hitting the code that tries to do this indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj yes you are absolutely right, sorry I forgot to explain those things. Thank you for correcting that. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the traceback `T[k, k+1]` doesn't work because `T` is a `bsr` format sparse matrix, which does not implement indexing.  (`coo` is a more common format that doesn't have this either).

### kron may make bsr

Looking at the `sp.kron` code, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.kron.html

```
if (format is None or format == "bsr") and 2*B.nnz >= B.shape[0] * B.shape[1]:
    # B is fairly dense, use BSR
    A = csr_matrix(A,copy=True)
    ...
    return bsr_matrix((data,A.indices,A.indptr), shape=output_shape)
```

So in `sp.kron(number(N), np.identity(2))`

```
In [251]: B = sparse.coo_matrix(np.identity(2))
In [252]: B
Out[252]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [253]: 2*B.nnz >= B.shape[0]*B.shape[1]
Out[253]: True

In [254]: sparse.kron(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2), np.identity(2))
Out[254]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 12 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>
```

### testing

```
In [258]: lg.expm(sparse.kron(np.identity(6), np.identity(2)))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:144: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve requires A be CSC or CSR matrix format
  warn('spsolve requires A be CSC or CSR matrix format',
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:215: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '
Out[258]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

changing to `csc` to get avoid this warning:

```
In [265]: lg.expm(sparse.kron(np.identity(6), np.identity(2)).tocsc())
Out[265]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 12 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

So simply providing a `bsr` to `expm` doesn't cause your error.  Looks like we'd have to examine `expm` what else happening.  I looked at this function (and MATLAB's) years ago.  It uses a `pade` approximation that includes a `inv` (which is `spsolve(I,A)`).  It's a complex function that tries different things, including different `Pade` orders.

So you'll have to tell us more about this `number` and the nature of the `kron()` result.  None of my guesses reproduce your error.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.expm

### upper triangular

Correction, the traceback tells us that it detect that your matrix is `upper triangular`:

```
if structure == UPPER_TRIANGULAR:
    # Invoke Code Fragment 2.1.
    X = _fragment_2_1(X, h.A, s)
```

so there's more code to trace through.

In any case doing the `tocsc` conversion before passing the matrix to `expm` might solve the problem:

```
lg.expm(sp.kron(...).tocsc())
```

### test small upper triangular array

```
In [268]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,4,5],[0,0,6]])
In [269]: M = sparse.bsr_matrix(A)
In [270]: M
Out[270]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements (blocksize = 1x1) in Block Sparse Row format>
```

Your error:

```
In [271]: lg.expm(M)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:144: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve requires A be CSC or CSR matrix format
  warn('spsolve requires A be CSC or CSR matrix format',
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:215: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-271-d1b1437dc466>", line 1, in <module>
    lg.expm(M)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 592, in expm
    return _expm(A, use_exact_onenorm='auto')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 677, in _expm
    X = _fragment_2_1(X, h.A, s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 813, in _fragment_2_1
    t_12 = scale * T[k, k+1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/bsr.py", line 315, in __getitem__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

with csc correction:

```
In [272]: lg.expm(M.tocsc())
Out[272]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

### with `np.diag(np.arange(N))`

```
In [303]: sparse.kron(np.diag(np.arange(3)), np.identity(2)).A
Out[303]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.]])
In [304]: sparse.kron(np.diag(np.arange(5)), np.identity(2))
Out[304]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 16 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>
In [305]: sparse.kron(np.diag(np.arange(6)), np.identity(2))
Out[305]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>
```

No significant difference in the `kron` result except size as `N` grows.

```
In [308]: lg.expm(sparse.kron(np.diag(np.arange(6)), np.identity(2)))
 ...
    t_12 = scale * T[k, k+1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/bsr.py", line 315, in __getitem__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Specifying a `csc` format in `kron` avoids that error (we can ignore this efficiency warning):

```
In [309]: lg.expm(sparse.kron(np.diag(np.arange(6)), np.identity(2),'csc'))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:82: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
Out[309]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 23 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Why `N=6` gives this warning and not small `N` probably has to do with which `Pade` order it had to try.  Keep in mind that `expm` is a complex calculation, and the best it can do (numerically) is approximate it.  That approximation is easier with small matrices.  There's a lot of math theory behind this code.